# Excel Macro VBA to create a hyperlink to another sheet based on the active cell content

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am trying create a hyperlink that links to a cell in another sheet in the same workbook which bases on the text of the cell. I've tried to do it manually and here is the result :

```
    =HYPERLINK("[Five Ecom - Floor Plan.xlsx]Inventory!" & 
     ADDRESS(MATCH('8th'!F9,Inventory!$A$1:$A$2000,0),1),'8th'!F9)
```

- `'8th'!F9` - is the current cell
- `Inventory!$A$1:$A$2000` - range of the cell destinations

The friendly text would be the content of the same current cell.

I'm particularly having difficulties on string manipulation here so I decided to separate the code into several variables, to which up to now I am unable to produce the desired output and results into Run-time error '1004'.

```
Public Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim z As String
    Dim c As String

    For Each cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If cell <> "" Then
            c = ActiveCell.Value
            x = "=HYPERLINK(""[Five Ecom - Floor Plan.xlsm]Inventory!"" & ADDRESS(MATCH("""
            y = """, Inventory!$A$1:$A$2000,0),1),"""
            z = """)"
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x & c & y & c & z
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro will work if you replace:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x & c & y & c & z
```

with:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = x & c & y & c & z
```

This assumes that the *Match()* finds what it is looking for.
For all the cells in `Selection` use:

```
Public Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim z As String
    Dim c As String

    For Each cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If cell <> "" Then
            c = cell.Value
            x = "=HYPERLINK(""[Five Ecom - Floor Plan.xlsm]Inventory!"" & ADDRESS(MATCH("""
            y = """, Inventory!$A$1:$A$2000,0),1),"""
            z = """)"
            cell.Formula = x & c & y & c & z
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

*(Assuming you need the content of each cell to be the "friendly name")*